# Javascript on Pocket PC Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events, pocketpc, pocket-ie

I have a problem with JavaScript not working in IE on Pocket PC.

The HTML is on the PDA loading locally, it has a simple function to show/hide SPAN tags:

```
function More(id) {
  if (document.getElementById(id).style.display=='block') {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display='none'; } 
  else { document.getElementById(id).style.display='block'; }
}
```

Called like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:More('a')">click here</a>
<span id="a">Hidden text</span>
```

This works perfectly well using IE on Windows Mobile 5/6, but just doesn't do anything on Pocket PC.

As a test I have tried getting the JavaScript to do simpler things directly from the onclick part of the anchor tag.  The only thing that worked was alert() with hard coded text.

Is there a trick to getting JavaScript to work on Pocket PC?

I am using Pocket PC 4.20.0 (Build 14053).

Answer (score 0):

PIE and PIE 2.0 only support JScript (which is not the same as Javascript). At IE mobile 6.0 Javascript support was added.